# Generate n consecutive dates with even day-part after today's date (for example for 2020-06-08 it will be 2020-06-10, 2020-06-12, 2020-06-14 ect.)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures, recursive-query

i need a bit help  i dont know wat is wrong in my code . Plz help.

```
create procedure  consecutive_N_even_day
@n  int 
as
begin
declare @na int
set @na = 0
declare @nexndate date
declare @date date
set @date=GETDATE()
declare @datepart int



while(@na<@n)
    begin
    
    set @nexndate=DATEADD(DAY,@na,@date)
    set @datepart=DATEPART(day,@nexndate)

    if @datepart%2=0
        begin
            
            print @nexndate;
            
        end
    set @na=@na+1
    
    end
    
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive query for this:

```
with cte as (
    select dateadd(day, day(getdate()) % 2, cast(getdate() as date)) dt, 0 n
    union all 
    select dateadd(day, 2, dt), n + 1 from cte where n < @n
)
select * from cte
```

The query starts from today (if it is an even day) or tomorrow, and then produces a series of dates with a 2 days increment. It iterates `@n` times.

You don't specify what to do if we reach the end of a month that has an uneven number of days. It is always possible to adapt the logic of the recursive part of the query to what you actually need in this case.

If `@n` is greater than `100`, you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.